# match string with regular expression

Tags: regex, python-2.7

```
import re
re1=open("sample.xml")
#actual string is as follows 
#"},{comp_code,"OK"
x='\"\}\,\{comp\_code\,\"OK\"'

for line in re1:
    if r'x' in line:
        print "found"
```

Above code return true even if string is not present and I am unable to figure it out

Comment: You have not used a regex at all, you only prepared a pattern and are checking if a `line` contains a literal `x`.

Comment: I think you tried to use it like `if re.search(x, line):`, but you also need to use a raw string when declaring the pattern: `x=r'\"\},\{comp_code,\"OK\"'`.

Comment: thanks ..let me try this :)

Comment: Note that `re.match` searches for the match only at the start of the string.

Comment: okay..i am trying with re.search

Comment: this seem to be working fine...thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not used a regex in your code, as you only prepared a pattern and are checking if a `line` contains a literal `x` character.

Use a raw string literal when declaring the pattern:

```
x=r'\"\},\{comp_code,\"OK\"'
```

and use `re.search(x, line):` instead of `if r'x' in line:` to check for a match, since `re.match` will only look for a match at the beginning of a string.